# A number validation issue. .5 is not a number but 0.5 is?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is the Model that gets validated.

```
public class EstimateItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public decimal PerUnitCost { get; set; }
    public string PerUnitDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:n0}")]
    [Min(1, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be zero")]
    public int Units { get; set; }

    public string UnitsDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsBasedOnHomeSquareFootage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    //[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c2}")]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public List<EstimateItemOption> Options { get; set; }

    public decimal ItemTotal { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Text box that fills the model.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Categories[c].EstimateGroups[g].EstimateItems[i].PerUnitCost,
new { @disabled = "disabled", @onchange = "costUpdate(this);", @cstType = "perUnit" })
```

This is the javascript that is handled when called @onChange

```
case 'perUnit':
    var it = $(src).closest('.itemRow').find("input[cstType='cost']");
    var gt = parseFloat(et.html().replace('$', '').replace(',', ''));
    et.html(gt - parseFloat(it.val()));
    if ($(src).closest('.itemRow').find('[hs]').attr('hs') == 'True') {
        var nv = $(src).val();
        if (nv == null || nv.length == 0) nv = 0;
        it.val(Math.round(nv * parseFloat($('#SquareFootage').val()) * 100) / 100)
        $(src).closest('.itemRow').find('.hcst').val(it.val());
        et.html(CurrencyFormatted(parseFloat(et.html()) + parseFloat(it.val())));
    } else {
        var nv = $(src).val();
        if (nv == null || nv.length == 0) nv = 0;
        it.val(Math.round(nv * parseFloat($(src).closest('.itemRow').find("input[cstType='units']").val()) * 100) / 100)
        $(src).closest('.itemRow').find('.hcst').val(it.val());
        et.html(CurrencyFormatted(parseFloat(et.html()) + parseFloat(it.val())));
    }
    break;
```

I need to know if why the textbox will not let me use a decimal less than 1 like a .5 
it says that perunitcost has to be a number

Comment: Can you explain what that javascript is supposed to do?  What does the `et` variable represent?

Comment: Have you determined if the failure is caused by the C# code or the Javascript code?

Comment: What is `CurrencyFormatted`?

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that Nv is the value of the textbox int eh javascript and i put alerts it seems to fail in the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this to force the input to a number:

```
case 'perUnit':
    var input = $(src), // may as well cache this as you're using it six times.
        it = input.closest('.itemRow').find("input[cstType='cost']"),
        gt = parseFloat(et.html().replace('$', '').replace(',', '')),
        nv = parseFloat(input.val(), 10); // parse to a float to ensure a number
    et.html(gt - parseFloat(it.val()));
    if (!nv) { // nv is now either a number, or NaN, so using truthy/falsy to determine if NaN
        nv = 0; // technically, 0 is falsy but this sets it to 0 anyway, so not an issue.
    }
    if (input.closest('.itemRow').find('[hs]').attr('hs') == 'True') {
        it.val(Math.round(nv * parseFloat($('#SquareFootage').val()) * 100) / 100)
        input.closest('.itemRow').find('.hcst').val(it.val());
        et.html(CurrencyFormatted(parseFloat(et.html()) + parseFloat(it.val())));
    } else {
        it.val(Math.round(nv * parseFloat(input.closest('.itemRow').find("input[cstType='units']").val()) * 100) / 100)
        input.closest('.itemRow').find('.hcst').val(it.val());
        et.html(CurrencyFormatted(parseFloat(et.html()) + parseFloat(it.val())));
    }
    break;
```